# Is there possible to apply Flaash atmospheric correction on sentinel-2?

Tags: sentinel2

I have to use specifically FLAASH atmospheric correction on sentinel-2 for my study project, I know we can't call xml file after 2016, so I tried to open sentinel band by band and add every detail for every band, then layer stack all of them, and it seems working. but ultimately after Flaash is done the output image is all too light kinda blue!!! before Flaash I also tried radiometric correction and without radiometric correction. I also tried converting sentinel data to envi format in snap. but still the result is the same.
I wonder if anyone encounter this problem and could help me, I would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.